# member access within null pointer of type 'struct ListNode'

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};

class Solution {
public:
    bool hasCycle(ListNode *head) {
        if(head == NULL) return false;
        ListNode* walker = head;
        ListNode* runner = head;
        while(runner->next != NULL && walker->next != NULL){
            walker = walker->next;
            runner = runner->next->next;
            if(walker == runner) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

I was practicing an interview code which seemed to be pretty simple. I have to return a bool that determines whether or not the singly-linked list has a cycle. I made two pointers walker which moves 1 step and runner which moves 2 steps every iteration.

But then this code gave me an error:

```
Line 15: member access within null pointer of type 'struct ListNode'
```

What causes that error?

Comment: Is there some static code analysis tool running over that code?

Comment: Moving two steps each iteration is dangerous, no? How do you know the list has an even number of elements?

Comment: I suggest you learn to use a debugger.

Comment: it looks like you need a [rubber_duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You only make sure that `runner->next` is not null, however after assignment

`runner = runner->next->next;`

`runner` can become null.

Comment: Same for `walker`.

Comment: @juanchopanza It is not the same for `walker` at it is assigned `walker->next` that is checked for null.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it:

```
bool hasCycle(ListNode *head) {
    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL) { return false; }
    struct ListNode * walker = new ListNode(1);
    struct ListNode * runner = new ListNode(2);
    walker = head;
    runner = walker->next;
    while(walker != fast){
        if(runner == NULL || runner->next == NULL) { return false; }
        walker = walker->next;
        runner = runner->next->next;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//- If a loop from circular path then there is hundred% chance that they will going to meet at some point so here we are taking a walker which move one step and a runner which move two step.

```
bool hasCycle(ListNode *head){
if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
       return false; 

struct ListNode *temp  = head; 
struct ListNode *walker; 
struct ListNode *runner;
walker = runner= head;
while(temp ){
  walker = walker->next;
  runner = runner->next->next;
    if(runner == walker) // as soon both get at same address we got return as 
     true value.
     { return True; }
    temp = temp->next;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Below Code should work fine.
It is the classic **Hare-Tortoise** theorem, where the hare takes 2 steps(distance units) while the tortoise goes by 1.

I think you did not check the nullity of **`runner->next->next`** which has caused this error

```
bool hasCycle(ListNode *head) 
{
    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL) 
    { 
       return false;
    }
    ListNode* tortoise=new ListNode();
    ListNode* hare = new ListNode();
    tortoise=head;
    hare=tortoise->next;
    while(tortoise != hare)
    {
        if(hare == NULL || hare->next == NULL) 
        { 
           return false; 
        }
        tortoise=tortoise->next;
        hare=hare->next->next;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sort answer is here with explanation**

> It returns the error because `runner=runner->next->next` can be NULL
> and you are checking runner->next!=NULL in while conditioning so you
> have to do a little change In your code In order to get your answer In
> while condition check for `runner->next->next!=NULL` and get the right
> answer.

Comment: What is the source of this quote?